# showModalDialog in Chrome is always maximised

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, showmodaldialog

I'm trying to open non-maximised dialogs using showModalDialog, but in Chrome they are always opening maximised. Anyone have any ideas why? It is fine in Firefox.

I've put a working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv3mt/):

```
<a href="javascript:void 0;"
   onclick="showModalDialog('http://jsfiddle.net/');">Go</a>
```

Comment: I think modal dialogs are a little out of fashion nowadays. Why not just use `window.open`? On Chrome, it's not modal anyway.

Comment: True. I've just tried changing it to window.open, but those seem to be opening in maximum size too. It works fine in Chrome Stable, but appears broken in the version of chromium I was using, 12.0.702.0 (77916).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I was launching Chrome with `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximised`, and this was propagating to child windows. I changed it to `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal` and cleared my Chromium user profile, and now it is fine.